# How to grant Lambda an access to RDS using CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

There is this [very nice abstraction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-dynamodb.Table.html#grant-wbr-read-wbr-write-wbr-datagrantee) when using DynamoDb:

```js
table.grantReadWriteData(lambda);
```

[This development](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/) gave me hope to have the same for RDS.

Comment: You need to create Aurora Serverless RDS Cluster with Data Api enabled. Here's a good example https://github.com/goranopacic/dataapi-demo